# Play custom sound on receiving notification in react-native app on android

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo-notifications

I need to play a custom sound `./android/app/src/main/res/raw/s4.mp3` when a notification is received to a react native application on android device from the server.

I am using following command to run my react-native application on android device, that is connect my pc with a USB cable.

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

It works all fine except playing required sound on receiving a message from server.

In `./android/app/src/main/java/com/channel92news/push/MainActivity.java`  I have following code to set the sound for channel `down_alerts`

```
NotificationChannel ntc = new NotificationChannel("down_alerts", "main", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).
setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH).build();
ntc.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/s4"), att);
```

At server (using python exponent_server_sdk)  I have simple line to send alerts which works

```
from exponent_server_sdk import PushMessage, PushClient
PushClient().publish_multiple([push_message1, push_message2])
```

The detail of push_message1 & push_message2 is

```
push_message1 = PushMessage(
  title="Server side notification", body="Message is pushed from server using PushClient().publish_multiple",
  channel_id="down_alters",
  to=token_value1
)
push_message2 = PushMessage(
  title="Server side notification", body="Message is pushed from server using PushClient().publish_multiple",
  channel_id="down_alters",
  to=token_value2
)
```

My main code in react-native App.js is

```
//get token
let expo_token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
if(expo_token){
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    console.log('Setting notification channel');
    //set channel
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('down_alerts', {
      name: 'main',
      sound: 's4.mp3',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
    });
  }
}

//register receive notification listener
Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

This console.log results as following when the notification pushed by server and received at client.

```
{
   "date": 1688637867600,
   "request": {
      "content": {
         "autoDismiss": true,
         "badge": null,
         "body": "Message is pushed from server using PushClient().publish_multiple",
         "data": [Object],
         "sound": "default",
         "sticky": false,
         "subtitle": null,
         "title": "Server side notification"
      },
      "identifier": "0:1688637867628864%40fad706f9fd7ecd",
      "trigger": {
         "channelId": "down_alters",
         "remoteMessage": [Object],
         "type": "push"
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately it **does not play s4.mp3**, but only default sound

Then I tried to schedule/create a local notification for test as

```
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
    title: "Client side test notification",
    body: 'This notification is sent using Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync',
  },
  trigger: {
    seconds: 1,
    channelId: 'down_alerts',
  },
});
```

**This client side test notification plays the required sound** when received, console.log(notification) produces following result for this one.

```
{
  "date": 1688635365006,
  "request": {
    "content": {
      "autoDismiss": true,
      "badge": null,
      "body": "This notification is sent using Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync",
      "data": null,
      "sound": "default",
      "sticky": false,
      "subtitle": null,
      "title": "Client side test notification"
    },
    "identifier": "c1e8cfab-d0d9-44cb-9f4d-54a78d55c8e9",
    "trigger": {
      "channelId": "down_alerts",
      "repeats": false,
      "seconds": 1,
      "type": "timeInterval"
    }
  }
}
```

What different I can do to **play my custom sounds on receiving notification from server?**